# How come onfocusin fires after onfocus, and after the element has received focus, even though it's supposed to fire before?

Tags: javascript, html

### The issue

[According to the W3C](https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-focus), the `focusin` event is supposed to fire before the element receives focus, and then the `focus` event is supposed to fire after. Instead, `focusin` fires after the element receives focus, and after `focus` fires.

### How things are supposed to be

I have heard from multiple sources including the W3C UI spec (at the bottom of this page) that when an element receives focus, the `focusin` event fires before it receives focus, and the `focus` event fires after it receives focus, meaning the order of events when clicking into and then out of an input *should* look like this:

User clicks input
`focusin` event fires
input gains focus
`focus` event fires
User clicks off
`focusout` event fires
input loses focus
`blur` event fires

### How things are

And yet in practice, it appears that they both fire **after** the element has received focus, and `focus` fires **before** `focusin`. Here's some code I used:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input id="i1" onfocus="f(event)" onfocusin="f(event)" onfocusout="f(event)" onblur="f(event)">
<script>
  const i = document.getElementById('i1');
  function f(event) {
    console.log(event.type + (document.activeElement === i ? ': focused' : ': NOT focused'));
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The log after clicking into and out of the input looks like this:

```
focus: focused
focusin: focused
blur: NOT focused
focusout: NOT focused
```

Which tells me that `focusin` is firing **after** the input gets focus, and not before, and `focusout` is firing after the input loses focus (that is, assuming I'm using `document.activeElement` right)
Not to mention that the order of the events is also wrong, since `focusin` and `focusout` should be before `focus` and `blur`, respectively.
If everything were working right, it should look like this:

```
focusin: NOT focused
focus: focused
focusout: focused
blur: NOT focused
```

This appears to work the same on Firefox and Chrome. Is something wrong with my browsers, or did I code something wrong?

---

### Sources

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusin_event
- https://caniuse.com/focusin-focusout-events
- https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#event-type-focus

From caniuse.com:

> The `focusin` and `focusout` events fire just **before** the element gains or loses focus, and they bubble. By contrast, the `focus` and `blur` events fire **after** the focus has shifted, and don't bubble.

From mozilla.org/.../focusin_event and .../focus_event:

> The `focusin` event fires when an element **is about to receive** focus.
> The `focus event` fires when an element **has received** focus.

From w3c.github.io:

> (Regarding `focusin`) This event type is similar to `focus`, but is dispatched **before** focus is shifted
> (Regarding `focus`) This event type is similar to `focusin`, but is dispatched **after** focus is shifted

Comment: What else can I say, except..., maybe just: File a Bug!

Comment: Done
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1745075

Comment: I edited the post and replaced `document.hasFocus(i)` with `document.activeElement === i` and changed the log results accordingly. The bug still stands.

Comment: https://github.com/w3c/uievents/issues/88